# Radius of convergence without the series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ be a power series, find the radius of convergence when

a)$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{3^n} = 1$

I'm not sure what the question is asking, how does the limit of $a_n/3^n$ help me find the radius of convergence?

Comment: What methods for determining the radius of convergence of a power series do you know?

Comment: @DanielFischer We haven't done any examples, but I know the root test and ratio test, as well as the definition of the radius of convergence as the supremum of a set $S = \{r\geq 0 | ... \}$

Comment: The root test and the ratio test both work with the given information. If you apply either of them to the given situation, what do you get?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand what information we're given, how can I compute $\dfrac{|a_{n+1}x^{n+1}|}{|a_nx^n|}$

Comment: You are given that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{3^n} = 1.$$ So you know quite a bit about the coefficients.

Comment: @DanielFischer I really don't see how - we don't have a $3^n$ in the original equation?

Comment: @DanielFischer $a_n \to 3^n$? Getting a radius of convergence of $1/3$?

Comment: Not quite $a_n \to 3^n$, but they differ by a factor close to $1$ for large $n$. The difference could however be unbounded, for example $a_n = 3^n + 2^n$ would satisfy the constraint.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, thank you for your solution - I still obtain an answer of $1/3$. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Oh, yes. The result of $1/3$ is correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just one more question (unrelated to this one), if we done the ratio test and received a result of $|a_{n+1}/a_n| \to \infty$ is that enough to conclude that $R = \infty$?

Comment: No, if $\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert \to\infty$, the radius of convergence is $0$. Did you mean to invert the quotient? Anyway, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right\rvert$ exists in $[0,+\infty]$, that is the radius of convergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please explain how the radius of convergence is 0 in that case?

Comment: If $\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert \to \infty$, then we have for every $x\neq 0$ $$\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}\right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert\cdot \lvert x\rvert \to\infty,$$ so the series does not converge for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the ratio test, you consider

$$\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}\right\rvert = \frac{3^{n+1}}{3^n}\left\lvert\frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}x^{n+1}}{\frac{a_n}{3^n}x^n}\right\rvert.$$

Now use the given

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n} = 1.$$